# How do I match a newline or the end of a file in a Raku grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

I have run into headaches trying to coerce a grammar to match the last line of a file if it is not followed by a newline:

```
Line 1
Line 2 EOF
```

This attempted solution, which makes the newline optional, causes an infinite loop:

```
my grammar HC4 {
    token TOP {  <line>+ }
    token line { [ <header> | <not-header> ] \n? } # optional newline

    token header { <header-start> <header-content> }
    token not-header { <not-header-content> }
    token header-start { \s* '#' ** 1..6 }
    token header-content { \N* }
    token not-header-content { \N* }
}
```

The `\N*` bits will match the `''` string after the last character in the last line forever.

I have tried using `<[\n\Z]>` but then the compiler complains and suggests using `\n?$` which I tried but that does not work either. After a lot of trial and error, the only solution I discovered that works requires me to create a new `<blank>` capture and to change the `\N*` to `\N+`:

```
my grammar HC3 {
    token TOP {  <line>+ }
    token line { [ <header> | <blank> | <not-header> ] \n? }

    token header { <header-start> <header-content> }
    token blank { \h* <?[\n]> }
    token not-header { <not-header-content> }
    token header-start { \s* '#' ** 1..6 }
    token header-content { \N+ }
    token not-header-content { \N+ }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a more straightforward accomplishing this, though. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Summary_of_anchors

Comment: Thanks. I have tried various combinations of `$` and `$$` but I still ran into the same problems with `\N*` matching nothing and causing infinite loops.

Comment: Ooh, wait. May have something. Will post an answer.

Comment: May be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263869/does-vi-silently-add-a-newline-lf-at-the-end-of-file

Comment: @jubilatious1 Very interesting. I do use vi. I'll look into this.

Comment: @jubilatious1 I found the issue. So IntelliJ/CommaIDE was the culprit. vim was saving the files just fine but when you save a file with intellij with no blank line showing at the end of the file, it does not add in the newline as it should. I confirmed this by dumping out the hex code of the file.

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have found something that can work and is simple:

```
my grammar G {
    token TOP {  (^^ <line>)+ }
    token line { \N* \n? }
}
```

The `^^` symbol, for the beginning of a line, stops the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

OK, after some investigation, I discovered the root cause of my woes:

[image]

This screenshot is from the IntelliJ IDE's Editor -> General settings. By default, the "Ensure every saved file ends with a line break" is not checked off. So if I saved a file with the very last line deleted to clean it up, it was stripping the last `\n` character. Check that setting on to avoid my pain, suffering and deep psychological trauma.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest solution is something like this:

```
grammar LineOriented {
    token TOP {
        <line>* %% \n
    }

    token line {
        ^^ \N*
    }
}
```

Using `%%` allows, but not requires, the last trailing line.